# sum up the whole element in the list given by the user skipping its first two elements

Tags: python, function

sum up the whole given list by user skipping its first two elements 
For example: `sum_of_marks(['ali','P176133',45,32,90,87)` it should return sum of the numbers

Comment: You mean `sum_of_marks(your_list[2:])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sum function

```
def sum_of_marks(lst):
    lst=['ali','P176133',45,32,90,87]
    return sum(lst[2:])

print sum_of_marks(['ali','P176133',45,32,90,87])
```