# How can i pass tuple as formal parameter in python

Tags: python

How to write a function that gives sum of its elements by skipping first two elements. It should handle if `None` is encountered

```
[('p101111', 'Kazmi', 64, 78.5, 89, 25, 99),
 ('p101112', 'Ali', 14, 28.5, None, 83, 76,60.5,34,32,89)]
```

Comment: What does this have to do with passing a tuple as a formal parameter?

Comment: This is essentially a repost of the same question posted a few hours ago which was marked as a duplicate, but not before an answer was posted and accepted.  [Here is the previous post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46998286/sum-up-the-whole-element-in-the-list-given-by-the-user-skipping-its-first-two-el)  It looks like the only difference is that now there are lists of tuples rather than a single list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code

```
def sum_of_marks(st):
    st=[i if i else 0 for i in st]
    return sum(st[2:])
lst=[
('p101111', 'Kazmi', 64, 78.5, 89, 25, 99),
('p101112', 'Ali', 14, 28.5, None, 83, 76,60.5,34,32,89),
]
for i in lst:
   print sum_of_marks(i)
```